# Client Machine uses Kerberos only when fiddler is open

Tags: iis-8

I'm trying to get my web app to use the users credentials when connecting to SQL which is on a different box to IIS.  I believe I have set up all the authentication settings, but it doesn't work and tries to connect as Negotiate(NTLM) except when Fiddler is open and it correctly uses Kerberos.

Why is fidder interfering, and how can I make it work without having fiddler open?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today. The root cause ended up being the DNS entry for the web application. It was setup as a CNAME to the IIS server. Switching it to an A record solved the issue. Make sure you allow enough time for DNS to replicate.

Comment: Fiddler acts as a proxy. [This Kb](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3022771) talks about proxies interfearing with Kerberos. Coincidence? I don't think so.